# How do you create the generic type in Map.entries()?

Tags: typescript

```
let out = [...m.entries()]
  .map(([k, v]) => [k, { foo: v }]) // <-- k has type of 1st param; v has type of 2nd param; perfect!
  .reduce((map, [k, fooV]) => { // <-- k & fooV has union type
    // Do stuff with it
    return map
  }, new Map())
```

When you iterate over a `Map.entries()` value, you can setup the parameters `[k,v]` to correspond to the 1st & 2nd parameters perfectly with their respective types.

However, when I try to do this myself, the types of `[k,fooV]` becomes a union type. I would like `k` & `fooV` to also have the type of 1st & 2nd parameter respectively.

In my mapper, I want to create the same type as `Map.entries()` so that the reducer's parameter can also destructure with the types intact.

From the docs, `Map.entries(): IterableIterator<[K, V]>;` makes `[K, V]` look like an array. But I tried that above and it doesn't work. What is `[K, V]`'s real type? How do you create an instance of it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy fix to also have good type inference in the `reduce` function. You can return the arrray with `as const` appended to the end.

```
let out = [...m.entries()]
  .map(([k, v]) => [k, { foo: v }] as const)  // <-- as const here
  .reduce((map, [k, fooV]) => { // <-- k & fooV have correct types now
  // Do stuff with it
  return map
}, new Map())
```

The initial problem is that types of *array literals* are often inferred with a wider type than what you might expect. By using `as const` we can force TypeScript to narrow down the type to be a tuple instead of any array.